# for loop failing to loop continuously

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var _target=document.querySelectorAll('.post .content');
    var isYT = /youtube|youtu.be/gi;
 for (i = 0; i < _target.length; i++) {
    var _tar = _target[i].children;
    for (var j = 0; j < _tar.length; j++) {
        var vidID;
        if (_tar[j].tagName == "A") {
            if (isYt.test(_tar[j].href) == true) {
                _eles.push(_tar[j]);
            }
        }
        if (_tar[j].tagName == "EMBED") {
            if (isYt.test(_tar[j].src) == true) {
                _eles.push(_tar[j]);
            }
        }
    } //end for loop j
} //end for loop i
  console.log(_eles);
```

The HTML looks sort of like this:

```
<div>
  <a href="www.youtu.be/i23ndf9">Video 1</a>
  <a href="www.youtube.com/v/349234">Video 2</a>
  <embed src="www.youtube.com/v/239324"></embed>
 </div>
<div>
  <a href="www.youtu.be/i23ndf9">Video 1</a>
  <a href="www.youtube.com/v/349234">Video 2</a>
  <embed src="www.youtube.com/v/239324"></embed>
 </div>
```

Though the returning array Object with my console logging is only showing one a element and one embed element. I have to continuously invoke this myself to get all the links and embeds to be placed into the array Object. Any one see any errors I've written, just been working on this issue for about 3 hours now and it is tiring me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: What is `_target` and `isYt`?

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: I think that only `isYt` could be wrong...

Comment: Notice, that IE is the only browser giving `tagName` in capitals, you better to use `xx.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a"`. What is `isYt`? (`'youtube'`?) Please check what `isYt.test()` actually returns.

Comment: updated. and thank you Teemu I will change the tagName to toLowerCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code this way:

```
var _target = document.querySelectorAll("div");
var _eles = [];
var isYt=new RegExp("\youtube.com");
for (var i = 0; i < _target.length; i++) {
    var _tar = _target[i].childNodes;
    for (var j = 0; j < _tar.length; j++) {
        var vidID;
        if(_tar[j].nodeType != 1) continue;
        if (_tar[j].tagName.toLowerCase() == "a") {
            if (isYt.test(_tar[j].href)) {
                _eles.push(_tar[j]);
            }
        }
        if (_tar[j].tagName.toLowerCase() == "embed") {
            if (isYt.test(_tar[j].src)) {
                _eles.push(_tar[j]);
            }
        }
    } //end for loop j
} //end for loop i
console.log(_eles);
```

and it works, check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2rLPf/2/)

but my favorite way to do this is like this:

```
var _target = document.querySelectorAll("div>a, div>embed");
var _eles = [];
var isYt=new RegExp("\youtube.com");
for (var j = 0; j < _target.length; j++) {
    var vidID;

    if (_target[j].tagName.toLowerCase() == "a") {
        if (isYt.test(_target[j].href)) {
            _eles.push(_target[j]);
        }
    }
    if (_target[j].tagName.toLowerCase() == "embed") {
        if (isYt.test(_target[j].src)) {
            _eles.push(_target[j]);
        }
    }
} //end for loop j
console.log(_eles);
```

for this check this one [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2rLPf/3/)

and if your `isYT` regexp is just as simple as I have used in my answer instead of all these lines of code you can simply do:

```
var _eles = document.querySelectorAll("div>a[href*='youtube.com/'],"+
                                    "div>embed[src*='youtube.com/']");
```

Comment: The only thing I had to change to your first code was that I actually had to loop the the isYT together in my situation for some reason. So the `var vidID` turned to this `var vidID,isYt = new RegExp('youtu','gi');` Thank you though as that was my biggest problem!